# Joining 3 dataframes, in which duplicate entries can be present

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I have a data frame like so...

```
df = tibble(id = c(64512, 64513, 64514, 64515), 
            customer=c("a", "a", "b", "b"))
```

and want to join two further data frames by `id` like these...

```
uvp_new = tibble(id=c(64512, 64513, 64514), uvp=c(12, 14, 16))

uvp_old = tibble(id=c(64512, 64515), uvp=c(10, 18))
```

with the following logic: whenever there is an entry for a `uvp` in `uvp_new`, i want to take this one (ignoring `uvp_old`), if there is no entry for `uvp` in `uvp_new`, i want to take the entry for `uvp` from `uvp_old`.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a full join between `uvp_new` and `uvp_old` to have all the id's in one dataframe and then join this combined dataframe with `df` and select the new uvp value if present or else the old one using  `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

uvp_new %>%
  rename(uvp_n = uvp) %>%
  full_join(uvp_old %>%
  rename(uvp_o = uvp), by = 'id') %>%
  right_join(df, by = 'id') %>%
  mutate(uvp = coalesce(uvp_n, uvp_o))

#     id uvp_n uvp_o customer   uvp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#1 64512    12    10 a           12
#2 64513    14    NA a           14
#3 64514    16    NA b           16
#4 64515    NA    18 b           18
```

You can remove `uvp_n` and `uvp_o` columns if they are not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can `left_join()` `uvp_old` and then use `rows_update()` with `uvp_new`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(uvp_old, by = "id") %>%
  rows_update(uvp_new, by = "id")

# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id customer   uvp
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1 64512 a           12
2 64513 a           14
3 64514 b           16
4 64515 b           18
```

Or it might be safer if there are duplicated ids in `df` to use `rows_upsert()` first and join the result to `df`:

```
uvp_old %>%
  rows_upsert(uvp_new, by = "id") %>%
  right_join(df, by = "id")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option using `transform` + `merge`

```
transform(
  merge(merge(df, uvp_new, by = "id", all.x = TRUE), uvp_old, by = "id", all.x = TRUE),
  uvp = ifelse(is.na(uvp.x), uvp.y, uvp.x)
)[c("id","customer","uvp")]
```

which gives

```
     id customer uvp
1 64512        a  12
2 64513        a  14
3 64514        b  16
4 64515        b  18
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the three together using two joins, keeping track of which data.frame the `uvp` column came from with `suffixes`. Then, you can select the first non-NA one with `coalesce`.

```
df %>% 
  left_join(uvp_new, by = "id") %>% 
  left_join(uvp_old, by = "id", suffix = c("_new", "_old")) %>% 
  mutate(uvp = coalesce(uvp_new, uvp_old))

#      id customer uvp_new uvp_old   uvp
#   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 64512 a             12      10    12
# 2 64513 a             14      NA    14
# 3 64514 b             16      NA    16
# 4 64515 b             NA      18    18
```